# Strange mesh behaviour when rendered

Tags: rendering, mesh, rigify

I have a scene set up with the astronaut model (it's a standard humanoid mesh with a rigify rig applied) in one scene and the black hole in another joined using alpha over node.
The mesh seems to be okay in object mode but as soon as I render this happens in every frame.
In the render preview in viewport it's also looking as it's supposed to.
[Here is the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-voMWbuilOiWDlzMHh0a0hjUHc)[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand what is wrong with the image."As is supposed to" might be clear for you but not for anybody else that was not looking over your shoulder while you created your scene... Please add images that show what you see in the viewport, and how you set your compositing nodes.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot to load the viewport image. It's there now. I don't really think it's the compositing's fault I just wanted to clarify the mesh isn't interacting with the "black hole" as it's rendered in an another scene.

Comment: Edited according to your guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is with using the file on different computers.
I didn't even think it could be a problem.
When I render it on my laptop the astronaut has his limbs, but when I send it over to my friend computer he doesn't have them in the viewport.